# GAE remote-api authentication

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, authentication

I have written an application which uses gae-remote-api with the following settings:

### app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /my_remote.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.remote_api.handler.application
```

### remote-app.py:

def auth_func():
    return 'my@gmail.com', 'my-password'

remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteDatastore(None, '/my_remote', auth_func, 'myapp.appspot.com')

---

This Application I have given to several people in the world. The problem is that sometimes Google does reject the remote_api_stup, because Google assumed a Hacker attack. Sometimes I have to enter a new password.

I have omitted the "login: admin" statement in app.yaml without effect.

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: How do you conclude that this is due to a suspected Hacker attack ? Does that somehow show in the logs ?

Comment: I got this message from google: "Hacker attack ...  IP-Adresse: 177.4.xxx.x; Standort: Rio Grande do Sul, Brasilien" and a user from Brasil reported problems with invalid password.